# Samsung Ativ book 9 lite install problems

Tags: installation, samsung

So i have an incredible amount of issues regarding installation of ubuntu on my laptop.

First of all the installation disc on usb does boot, but just ends up (after ubuntu logo) to a command line interface saying live image or something doesn't exist. even tried with virtual-box and same problem occurs. I did manage to install and boot from the netinstall, but then for some reason installed ubuntu studio and didn't always start the desktop after logging in. it just got stuck. but even so is there something wrong with the 64-bit 12.04 iso? i also tried with 32bit, but it didn't boot it.

I also have managed to install and boot Debian which worked, but it also found the same problems as it did with the netinstall ubuntu. which was no wifi, ethernet only worked first time, Debian complained about the driver for the graphics card not being present therefore not functioning properly.

please help find drivers and all the stuff i need to get it working. i hate being stuck with windows.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else should have any issues with installing ubuntu on the ativ 9 here is what you need to do.

One of the problems was making the USB. not managing to make it bootable in Windows, I made a Tails OS live USB from which I made the Ubuntu install USB. Then it worked. Why it didn't in windows i do not know.

Second problem:
When it boots from the USB and you can choose between **Try Ubuntu without Installing** and **Install Ubuntu**, choose install. 
The drivers for the graphics card are proprietary and do not automatically install, therefore you will not be able to start the desktop fully.

When installed and rebooted press CTRL + ALT + F1 to access console login.

Type in your username and password.

Then install `fglrx` with

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

(make sure you are connected to the internet.)

reboot and all is good :)

regarding the network card - this does not seem to be an issue after all.